# Metamodel does not generate field annotated with @Type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In a model class I have

```
@Type(type="balh.JsonConvertType")
@Column(name="tags")
private List<Tag> tags;
```

The database table contains the column `tags` which is a `varchar` column. But when i generate metamodel using JPA then this filed is not generated. How can i make feilds annotate with @Type to be generated into metamodel

Comment: Do you have a [@TypeDef](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2794) for the custom type?

Comment: is @TypeDef required ? or is it making it bad ?

Comment: Oh, I just see: You have a `List` of tags. A `List` cannot be annotated with `@Column` - and probably neither with `@Type`; to Hibernate the type of the field is `List`, period. - Have a look at [Collection mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-mapping).

Comment: @HannoBinder, hopefully some work around will appear soon. But for now im dropping all Type annotated once in classes related to lists. thank you

Comment: What are you trying to express? - Are the `Tag` instances actually of type `balh.JsonConvertType`?

Comment: Maybe `@OneToMany(targetEntity=balh.JsonConvertType.class)` is what you need.

Comment: ok. ill give it a try.